# Nginx regex in location block

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

What kind of regex patterns does Nginx location block allow? The request does not match and I get 404 error.

The request URL localhost:80/client/images/card.png

```
location / {
   root   html;
   index  index.html index.htm;
}

location ~/.*/images/ {
   root  C:/web;
}
```

error : CreateFile() C:\Users\Downloads\nginx-1.12.2\nginx-1.12.2/html/client/images/card.png

Comment: Is the file located at `C:/web/client/images/card.png`?

Comment: Yes, at C:/web/client/images/card.png

Comment: missing whitespace after "~"